# Define a method within a class which creates an instance of the class

Tags: ruby, class, hashmap

I'm writing a class `MyHashSet` that imitates the `Set` class. The elements of the set are contained as hash items reading `{element => true}`. Here is how it is defined:

```
class MyHashSet
  attr_accessor :store
  def initialize
    @store = {}
  end

  def insert(el)
    @store.merge!(el => true)
  end

  def include?(el)
    @store[el]
  end

  def delete(el)
    @store.select! {|key,value| key != el}
  end

  def to_a
    @store.keys
  end

  def self.union(set)
    result=MyHashSet.new
    result.store=(self.store).merge(set.store)
    result
  end
end
```

The last method `union` should be such that if I type the commands:

```
set1=MyHashSet.new
set2=MyHashSet.new

set1.insert("Mark Hamill")
set1.insert("Harrison Ford")
set1.insert("Anthony Daniels")

set2.insert("Ewan McGregor")
set2.insert("Natalie Portman")
set2.insert("Anthony Daniels")
```

and then try to compute

```
set3=set1.union(set2)
```

I should get a `set3` variable, which is an instance of `MyHashSet` such that its `store` is:

```
{"Mark Hamill"=>true, "Harrison Ford"=>true, "Anthony Daniels"=>true, "Ewan McGregor"=>true, "Natalie Portman"=>true}
```

However, if I try to run this I get an `undefined method` error message:

```
`<main>': undefined method `union' for #<MyHashSet:0x00000000f4e3b8> (NoMethodError)
```

I don't understand why Ruby does not pick this method.

Comment: You're calling a **class method** on an **instance**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use it like instance method not class method. And you can use `self.class.new` insted of `MyHashSet.new`

like this

```
class MyHashSet
  attr_accessor :store
  def initialize
    @store = {}
  end

  def insert(el)
    @store.merge!(el => true)
  end

  def include?(el)
    @store[el]
  end

  def delete(el)
    @store.select! {|key,value| key != el}
  end

  def to_a
    @store.keys
  end

  def union(set)
    result = self.class.new
    result.store = self.store.merge(set.store)
    result
  end
end
```

output

```
set1=MyHashSet.new
# => #<MyHashSet:0x1efea79 @store={}>
set2=MyHashSet.new
# => #<MyHashSet:0x34c75a @store={}>

set1.insert("Mark Hamill")
# => {"Mark Hamill" => true}
set1.insert("Harrison Ford")
# => {"Mark Hamill" => true, "Harrison Ford" => true}
set1.insert("Anthony Daniels")
# => {"Mark Hamill" => true, "Harrison Ford" => true, "Anthony Daniels" => true}

set2.insert("Ewan McGregor")
# => {"Ewan McGregor" => true}
set2.insert("Natalie Portman")
#=> {"Ewan McGregor" => true, "Natalie Portman" => true}
set2.insert("Anthony Daniels")
# => {"Ewan McGregor" => true, "Natalie Portman" => true, "Anthony Daniels" => true}

set3 = set1.union(set2)
# => #<MyHashSet:0x1c7cbad @store={"Mark Hamill"=>true, "Harrison Ford"=>true, "Anthony Daniels"=>true, "Ewan McGregor"=>true, "Natalie Portman"=>true}>
```

btw:

Maybe you can modify your `initialize` method for better usage like this

```
def initialize(store = nil)
  @store = store || {}
end
```

After this you can call `union` easly

```
def union(set)
  self.class.new(self.store.merge(set.store))
end
```

so your final clas will looks like this

```
class MyHashSet
  attr_accessor :store

  def initialize(store = nil)
    @store = store || {}
  end

  def insert(el)
    @store.merge!(el => true)
  end

  def include?(el)
    @store[el]
  end

  def delete(el)
    @store.select! { |key, value| key != el }
  end

  def to_a
    @store.keys
  end

  def union(set)
    self.class.new(self.store.merge(set.store))
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I found that the code works if I remove the "self." in front of "union":

```
class MyHashSet
  attr_accessor :store
  def initialize
    @store = {}
  end

  def insert(el)
    @store.merge!(el => true)
  end

  def include?(el)
    @store[el]
  end

  def delete(el)
    @store.select! {|key,value| key != el}
  end

  def to_a
    @store.keys
  end

  def union(set)
    result=MyHashSet.new
    result.store=(self.store).merge(set.store)
    result
  end
end
```

I suppose this is because the method is to be called on an instance of the class rather than on the class itself.

Comment: I recommend using `reject!` instead of `select!` in your case.